# No runtime can be found in Mobilefirst

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We installed the software's mentioned above

```
(a) WAS Liberty Profile 8.5.5.6
(b) Mobile First Server 6.3
(c) MySQL  5.1.73-community 
(d) JDK 1.7
```

We created `application server` and `runtime environment` through `Server configuration tool` but we face the error

> No runtime can be found

We tried many of the options from stack overflow and other questionnaires but nothing worked.

We are really stuck and not sure what should be done next and how to check whether deployment of runtime environment was successful or not (through Server configuration tool)

Please help us to fix this issue

We see following exceptions in log but not sure whether these exceptions are the root cause

```
[root@oc3855733574 Liberty]# cat ./usr/servers/simpleServer/logs/messages.log | grep "E " 
java.runtime = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (pxa6470sr9-20150417_01 (SR9))
[7/21/15 14:48:29:124 IST] 0000001d com.ibm.ws.config.internal.xml.ConfigUpdater                 E CWWKG0031E: The value worklight/ibm.worklight.admin.environmentid specified for unique attribute jndiName is already in use.
[7/21/15 14:48:38:826 IST] 00000019 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp                               E SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.worklight.common.i18n.MessageCatalog
[7/21/15 14:48:39:042 IST] 00000019 org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet          E com.worklight.authorization.endpoint.AuthorizationServerRestApplication
[7/21/15 14:48:39:114 IST] 00000019 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp                               E SRVE0276E: Error while initializing Servlet [OAuthAuthorizationServer]: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: com.worklight.authorization.endpoint.AuthorizationServerRestApplication
[7/21/15 14:48:39:269 IST] 00000019 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet                              E Uncaught.init.exception.thrown.by.servlet 
[7/21/15 14:48:39:274 IST] 00000019 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp                               E SRVE0266E: Error occured while initializing servlets: javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: Uncaught initialization exception created by servlet
[7/21/15 14:48:39:372 IST] 00000019 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter                               E SRVE0321E: The [OAuthServletFilter] filter did not load during start up.
[7/21/15 14:48:39:474 IST] 00000019 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter                               E SRVE0321E: The [authorizationServerFilter] filter did not load during start up.
```

Comment: sorry, forgot to add my name 'sathish kumar'

Comment: Please add the messages.log file and your server.xml file - upload them to either dropbox or google docs or pastebin or anywhere else.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/rzYqf86u  - server.xml
http://pastebin.com/iKuM6La7 - messages.log

Answer (score 0):

Based on the errors in the messages.log file it cannot find the Worklight JEE .jar file.

Based on the server.xml file, the file is not placed in its usual default location as set by the Installation process.

You need to verify that the location that appears in the server.xml file matches the location in the file system.

```
<application id="worklight" name="worklight" location="clsapp.war" type="war">
    <classloader delegation="parentLast">
        <privateLibrary id="worklightlib_worklight">
            <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/lib" includes="worklight-jee-library.jar"/>
            <fileset dir="${wlp.install.dir}/lib" includes="com.ibm.ws.crypto.passwordutil_1.0.1.jar"/>
        </privateLibrary>
    </classloader>
</application>
```

Typically the location would be `${shared.resource.dir}/lib/worklight` (or instead of "worklight" there would be Your context root...).